# Software to log torrent's peers

Tags: networking, logging, bittorrent, tracking

I'm looking for a software to track and log to a file torrents leecher's IP's.
uTorrent for an example doesn't offer this feature which makes sense since it's very lightweight and basic application. Are there any applications that offer tha

Comment: You should talk with the guys over at www.youhavedownloaded.com since they're doing that already.

Comment: Not sure if FBI...